# Understanding the Irreps of a Particular Representation of Symmetric Group Product

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, quantum-computation

I'm reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3826.pdf) on the element distinctness problem, and I'm having some trouble parsing Claim 2. I've recently been going through *The Symmetric Group* by Sagan (Chapters 1 and 2 so far).

Here's the premise. For an alphabet $\Sigma$ of size $n$, consider the list of distinct elements $z=(z_1,\dots, z_n)$. The index permutations $\pi\in S_n$ just change the order of lists:
$$z_\pi:=\pi z=(z_{\pi^{-1}(1)},\dots, z_{\pi^{-1}(n)}).$$
The alphabet permutations $\tau\in S_\Sigma$ relabel elements in the list:
$$z^\tau:=\tau z=(\tau(z_1),\dots, \tau(z_n)).$$

Now we consider the matrices $V^\tau_\pi$ which perform the map $V^\tau_\pi=z^\tau_\pi$. Here's where my questions start, as the the author states "**$V$ is isomorphic to the regular representation of $S_n$ and $S_\Sigma$.**'' So, I know that the regular representation of $S_n$ is just consists of the algebra $\mathbb C[S_n]$, meaning I need an $S_n$-isomorphism between $S_n$ and $V$, yet I'm unclear on what $V$ is. I'd think it'd be $V=\text{span}\{V^\tau_\pi\mid \pi\in S_n, \tau\in S_\Sigma\}$, but the basis $\{V^\tau_\pi\}$ obviously has more than $n!$ elements, so that led me to believe they're referring to $\{V_\pi^\varepsilon\}$ and $\{V^\tau_\varepsilon\}$, is this correct?

On the other hand, Claim 2 says that $$V\cong \bigoplus_{\lambda\vdash n}\lambda\times \lambda,$$ which led me to the following question: **When they say $V\cong \bigoplus_{\lambda\vdash n}\lambda\times \lambda$, is it convention for $\lambda$ to refer to the Specht module $S^\lambda$? Or is that even what they mean?** I think it should be more clear why the claim is true when I know the answers to these two questions.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be wary of spending a lot of time on a paper that doesn't even define $U$ and $V$, but I think it's likely that $V$ is actually $\mathcal{Y}$, which is presumably the free vector space on $\mathcal{D}_0$, which is the set of all sequences of length $N$ consisting of distinct elements of $\Sigma$, with action of the two permutation groups specified by the displayed equation before (2).

Comment: Re $\lambda$: they are using the convention described in the second paragraph of $\S$2.4.